# C помощью чего реализовать api/web interface

Tags: java

Есть приложение java se/swing для него необходимо реализовать веб интерфейс и возможность работы по api. Огромных потоков данных не будет, просто подобие веб интерфейса у роутера. Посоветуйте с помощью чего лучше всего реализовать?

Comment: с формального описания всех методов и параметров у них

Answer (score 1):

1. `WebView` на Swing
2. Запилить старый-добрый Java Applet со свинговыми контролами